# How to target an array in a struct in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So I wrote a program to use a struct and array to calculate max/min grade (and soon to be average) of students from a file. While I did figure out the minimum and maximum grades, I also want to add which student had the highest grade and lowest grade.How could I find the array line and display the .first and .last of the struct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

struct student {

    int id;
    string first;
    string last;
    float grade;
};

string getFileName();
void fillArrayFromFile(ifstream&, student[], int&);
float calculateMaximumGrade(student[], int);
float calculateMinimumGrade(student[], int);
float calculateAverageGrade(student[], int);



int main() {

    int numofStudents = 5;

    const int NUM_VALS = 5;

    student studentArray[NUM_VALS];
    ifstream filename;
    //filename.open(getFileName() + ".txt");

    fillArrayFromFile(filename, studentArray, numofStudents);

cout << "Highest grade: " << calculateMaximumGrade(studentArray,     numofStudents) << endl;
cout << "Lowest grade: " << calculateMinimumGrade(studentArray, numofStudents) << endl;
//cout << "Average grade: " << calculateAverageGrade(studentArray, numofStudents) << endl;

return 0;
}

string getFileName()
{
// To be completed

return 0;
}

void fillArrayFromFile(ifstream& ins, student studentArray[], int&   numberOfStudents)
{
ins.open("input.txt");



for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

    ins >> studentArray[i].id;
    ins >> studentArray[i].first;
    ins >> studentArray[i].last;
    ins >> studentArray[i].grade;

}

ins.close();

return;
}

// calculate the maximum grade in the array
float calculateMaximumGrade(student studentArray[], int numberOfStudents)
{
float max = 0;
max = studentArray[0].grade;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

    if (studentArray[i].grade > max) {

        max = studentArray[i].grade;

    }

}
return max;
}

// calculate the minimum grade in the array
float calculateMinimumGrade(student studentArray[], int numberOfStudents)
{
float min = 0;
min = studentArray[0].grade;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

    if (studentArray[i].grade < min) {

        min = studentArray[i].grade;

    }

}
return min;
}

// calculate the average grade in the array
float calculateAverageGrade(student studentArray[], int numberOfStudents)
{
// To be completed
return 0;
}
```

Comment: last is studentArray[numberOfStudents - 1], first is studentArray[0]

Comment: You can do the following .... while you are evaluating max value not just keep track of max value but also the object whose grade you assign to max variable. For this create a object of student type letSay MaxObject and assign MaxObject = student[i] under the if along side max = ...  and after loop display the fields of object you created.  And if you dont want to display in that function then you can pass a reference to a student object to this function and after this function end your sent referenced object will hold the values of max students. Same for displaying Min Student

Answer (score 0):

You need to store not only `max` in your `calculateMaximumGrade` function, but also the index of the element, which has that `max` grade.
That is:

```
int calculateMaximumGrade(student studentArray[], int numberOfStudents)
{
    float max = studentArray[0].grade;
    int index_of_max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

        if (studentArray[i].grade > max) {
            index_of_max = i;
            max = studentArray[i].grade;
        }

    }
    return index_of_max;
}
```

As you see, you can also return not `max`, but its `index`. Then you should do the following in your `main`:

```
int index_of_max = calculateMaximumGrade(studentArray,     numofStudents);
cout << "Highest grade: " << studentArray[index_of_max].grade << ". Student, who got it: " << studentArray[index_of_max].first << " " << studentArray[index_of_max].last << endl;
```

You should do the same with `Average` and `Min` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could change (and rename) your `calculateMinimumGrade` function to record the index of the student with the lowest grade and return that instead of the grade itself.

```
// find the student with the lowest grade
int findLowestStudent(student studentArray[], int numberOfStudents)
{
int lowest = 0;
float min = 0;
min = studentArray[0].grade;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

    if (studentArray[i].grade < min) {

        min = studentArray[i].grade;
        lowest = i;
    }

}
return lowest;
}
```

You can then use the index to access student's grade.

```
int lowest = findLowestStudent(studentArray, numofStudents);
cout << "Lowest grade: " << studentArray[lowest].grade << endl;
```

You can use the same index to access the name of the student. Obviously you'll need to make similar changes to `calculateMaximumGrade`.